# Maintaining gridview data between sessions ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-webpages

I'd like to save my current gridview's data in a static var/class/list/whatsoever so I have the current gridview data stored in it as I run the application. I already did it with Viewstate and Sessionstate.

I don't have a use for it, it's just about practicing on how to do that.

Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: As a rule you should never store user data in a static variable in an ASP.NET application because static variables are shared with all users and all sessions. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know its not practical much, Im just trying to complete a task I was given. for practice purposes, nothing more than that

Comment: You don't want to persist the gv data - that's going to cost HUGE in terms of performance. I would save the criteria you used to fill the grid, and then when returning to that page, you re-pull the data again and re-fill the grid. This will not only work better, but from a multi-user point of view, if new data been added or changed in the database, then the gv will reflect that new updated data. So, for all practical design considerations you don't want to persist that data but MUCH better to re-pull data from the database again. It will not only perform much better, but also show updated data

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot ! Indeed I dont have any reason to do that, just wanted to know if thats possible and if so how.. but I see what you're saying, indeed better that way! thanks again

Comment: If you looking for simple crud, or how the flow of editing data in gv looks and works? Try running this live web example I have - it will give you some UI ideas. In this example, I have a "edit" button on each row of the GV, and I pop a edit dialog. But, NOTE VERY close, if you edit/change data in that edit, when you close the edit dialog, the GV updates. Live sample here: http://www.kallal.ca/Website11/WebForm2

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal well thanks, I already have a functioning gridview, I was just given a task to save the data statically ... so Im trying to complete it still with no success tho.